# Use JavaScript arrays instead of loading OBJ or GLTF in three.js for performance

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js, gltf

Loading OBJ/GLTF/GLB models into my three.js application takes some time, while declaring JavaScript arrays of vertices and indices of the same data and creating a new object is much faster (and less file size).

Is this good practice however? Is there a compelling reason as why to load a 3D file format instead of using JavaScript arrays which seem faster?

Comment: I don't know the formats, but I think that a specialized format like OBJ occupies less space than a textual representation of a JS array.

Comment: One of my models takes 600KB for OBJ, 300KB for GLB and 50KB for the javascript arrays.

Comment: Really? Are you sure there's no extra information in there, like textures?

Comment: This is a textureless model

Comment: Are you compressing the js file? What is it, json?

Answer (score 2):

It is highly unlikely that the same data, can be so much smaller. You most likely have compression enabled for your "js arrays" format, and not for gltf, or obj